# getting the error "malformed header from script" moving some old legacy perl code

Tags: perl, cgi

I am moving some really old legacy perl cgi code to a new server.

All the old perl stuff seems to be working except one script and one line.

I am not sure if i have forgotten to load something (usually it tells me i am missing something)

the line of code that causes the error:

```
print $query->redirect(-location=>"/servlet/guestbookServlet?method=displayGuestBook&dir=kam");
```

the error in the errorlog is

```
 malformed header from script. Bad header=HTTP/1.0 "/servlet/guestbookSe: guestbook.pl
```

if i put in malformed header from script. Bad header=HTTP/1.0 "/servlet/guestbookSe: guestbook.pl durectly in the browser it is fine

if i put

```
print header
print $query->redirect(-location=>"/servlet/guestbookServlet?method=displayGuestBook&dir=kam");
```

the browser just prints out ( which i am not sure really look correct?)

```
HTTP/1.0 "/servlet/guestbookServlet?method Status: "/servlet/guestbookServlet?method
Window-target: kam" Set-cookie: displayGuestBook&dir Expires: -Status Date: Tuesday, 
31-Dec-2013 14:04:37 GMT -Location http://www1.mydomain.com/cgi-local/guestbook.pl?
action: -URI http://www1.mydomain.com/cgi-local/guestbook.pl?action: -nph 0 Content-
type: LOCATION
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
print $query->redirect("/servlet/guestbookServlet?method=displayGuestBook&dir=kam");
```

without the `-location`. Also check the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI) under [GENERATING A REDIRECTION HEADER](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER).